# how to display all method of an activeX control

Tags: php, com, activex

I installed my Activex control using setup.exe and then I register it with command :

```
regsvr32 UpdateCreator.ocx
```

I use COM class to create the object `ex`.But I can't display any method of this class . Although I can use the method `getMethods`.

I use this PHP code for that :

```
<?PHP

    $ex = new COM("UpdateCreator.updCreator", NULL, CP_UTF8) or Die ("Did not instantiate ");
    $class = new ReflectionClass('COM');
    var_dump(get_class_methods($ex));
    echo get_class($ex);
    echo "\n";
    var_dump(get_object_vars($ex));
    $method = $class->getMethods();
    var_dump($method);
    $sn= '124dd';
    $hid= 'dfgh';
    $answer= 'ertyy';
    $rand = 'jkjkj';
    $int = $ex->getAnswer($sn, $hid, $answer, $rand);
    echo $int;
?>
```

the result :

```
  C:\xampp\php>php.exe d:\testCom.php
    array(0) {
    }
    com
    bool(false)
    array(0) {
    }
0
```

how to display method used by the object ex ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
var_dump(get_class_methods('COM'));
```

Comment: is the same problem it doesn't display methods

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in the com_dotnet extension that does this : [com_print_typeinfo()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.com-print-typeinfo.php)

When I needed it, it worked. I don't have much experience with it, so I don't know if it works with all COM objects. Also the syntax is somehow cryptic, at least for someone like me that didn't write activX code before.